# Form highlight and outline size

Tags: html, css, forms, input, field

So I have a field that is supposed to have a black outline. Like this

[image]

Where the 237 is. But here's what I have

```
.r{
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 100px;   
    font-family: 'proxima_novalight';
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    outline: 3px solid black;
}
```

For some reason when I select the field it gets smaller. And on initial load, there's kind of like an outline around it. A grayish one. You could call it a shadow [Here's](http://jsbin.com/cuwurowu/1/edit) a demo. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `border` instead of `outline` to remove the "shadow":

```
.r{
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 100px;   
    font-family: 'proxima_novalight';
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
```

**JSBin:** http://jsbin.com/cuwurowu/2/edit

Comment: Marking you as answer cause the size change issue is fixed, and my original issue is. Plus a demo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The “shadow” is the default border of the `input` element. To remove it, add

```
.r { border: none }
```

(but note that this affects the totals dimensions of the element, which may matter in pixel-exact layout).

The shrinking effect in Chrome (does not seem to happen in Firefox or IE) is apparently caused by a browser default style sheet that sets `outline-offset: -2px` on the element when it is focused. The `outline-offset` sets the distance between an outline and the outer edfes of the element, so a negative value shrinks the outline. To fix this, add

```
 .r { outline-offset: 0 }
```